# Extract data from Nike+ Sportband with PyUSB on Debian

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, pyusb

I have an old Nike+ Sportband ([image here](http://thefutureofthings.com/upload/items_icons/Nike-Sportband_large.jpg)). Nike has decided to remove support for this product. I would like to extract the data and then decode it. Someone wrote a code in C that works ([link download](http://knz-blue.cocolog-nifty.com/memo/files/SportBandUtility20101202.tar.gz)). I want to do it in Python, so I have decided to use **PyUSB**.

**Code**:

```
import sys
import usb.core
import usb.util

VENDOR_ID = 0x11ac
PRODUCT_ID = 0x4269

device = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_ID, idProduct=PRODUCT_ID)

print device

if device is None:
    sys.exit("Device not found.")

if device.is_kernel_driver_active(0):
    try:
        device.detach_kernel_driver(0)
        print('Kernel driver detatched.\n')
    except usb.core.USBError as e:
        sys.exit("Could not detatch kernel driver: %s" % str(e))

try:
    device.set_configuration()
    #device.reset()
    print('Configuration Ok')
except usb.core.USBError as e:
    sys.exit("Could not set configuration: %s" % str(e))


# read a data packet
data = device.read(0x81,8,10000)

print data
```

I always get this error:

```
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 110] Operation timed out
```

Any suggest?

Comment: A cursory look at the C code suggests that it will send a control message to the device first, "asking" it for specific types of responses (`usb_control_msg` calls), but it doesn't look like you're doing anything like that here.  Sounds like a fun project though.

Comment: @jedwards Yes maybe it's too difficult for me. I have not yet tried to send messages with PyUSB, moreover (if I understood correctly) I need an OUT endpoint but I have only found an IN endpoint. But thank you, I can try to send a message and then try to read it.